# How do I create a multi-page application using Swift for OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I've created an OS X Cocoa Application using the Swift language in Xcode. I have setup my main storyboard like this:

[image: Main Storyboard]

And when I run the application and hit the button, it opens a new window for the other View Controller like this which is not what I want. This is what I get:

[image: Display]

What I want exactly is that the ViewControllers to switch but in the same window, and not in a new window. How do I stop the new window behaviour and make this work in the same window?

Comment: If you're looking for more attention for your question there's some advice in the help centre, but posting comments isn't one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your ViewController where your button action is:

```
@IBAction func changeView(sender: AnyObject) {
    let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as? SecondViewController
    view.window?.contentViewController = secondVC
}
```

And remember to identify your second viewcontroller like this
[image]

Comment: Hmmm...I just tested it and it works. I don't have any segue, I just put viewcontroller to storyboard, sublassed nsviewcontroller "SecondViewController" +identify that and then it works.

Comment: Oh, I have segue'd my button to the secondviewcontroller. I'll remove that segue and test.